# How can I make my API website json value into a new variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to convert a username to an ID. Here’s my API link: https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/username (username is replaced by the variable “name”.) So from that link I need to get the ID value and save it to a variable called “uuid”.

Thanks,
Nathan

Here’s a valid url for viewing: https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/_Pine

Comment: url not working

Comment: @AbhishekSingh sorry I fixed it

Comment: question is not clear. where are you using this API and in which language?

Comment: I’m not sure it said it’s an api but it makes a json I think, but I need JavaScript to convert it to an var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you fetch the JSON object from that API, you need to parse it using JSON.parse(). So, for example:

```
let myUserInfo = JSON.parse(fetchResult);
let uuid = myUserInfo.id;
```

So, given that you currently don't know about [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), I'd suggest learning that. `fetch` is a javascript Promise object, a new part of the language that greatly simplifies grabbing data from open API's (for example). Here's a simple fetch statement for that URL:

```js
let myUserUrl = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/_Pine";


fetch(myUserUrl)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson.id);
  });
```

Note that this won't run on stackoverflow, as it crashes into a cross-origin error. Depending on where and how you are serving this, let us know if it works for you, or if you get stuck.

Comment: Of course, that assumes you know how to fetch an API from javascript...

Comment: Idk what or how to do that

Comment: All that said, there is an example of using the Mojang API with javascript on github: https://github.com/minecrafter/mojang-api -- be warned, this **is** a complex subject. Not for the faint of heart.